# UIPageViewController transition not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with a page curl (not that the transition type matters as neither works), where the second page doesn't display until the animation is finished. The code use to work, but no longer, any ideas would be great

[image: Not working]

The code is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    // other code deleted, for easy reading
}


- (PsalmViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.mDelegate.mPsalms count] == 0) || (index >= [self.mDelegate.mPsalms count]))
        return nil;

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PsalmViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PsalmViewController"];
    PsalmData *data = [self.mDelegate.mPsalms objectAtIndex:index];
    [controller setupView:index psalm:data];
    self.mNextPsalm = controller;

    return controller;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.mNextIndex == 0 || self.mNextIndex == NSNotFound)
        return nil;

    self.mNextIndex = self.mPageIndex - 1;
    self.mAnimating = true;
    NSLog(@"Prev %lud", (unsigned long)self.mNextIndex);
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.mNextIndex];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.mNextIndex == NSNotFound)
        return nil;

    if (self.mNextIndex + 1 == [self.mDelegate.mPsalms count])
        return nil;

    self.mNextIndex = self.mPageIndex + 1;
    self.mAnimating = true;
    NSLog(@"Next %lu", (unsigned long)self.mNextIndex);
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.mNextIndex];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.mDelegate.mPsalms count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray<UIViewController *> *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    if (completed)
    {
        self.mPageIndex = self.mNextIndex;
        [self setCurrentPsalm:self.mNextPsalm];
    }
    else if (finished)
    {
        self.mNextIndex = self.mPageIndex;
    }

    if (completed || finished)
        self.mAnimating = false;
    NSLog(@"C %d F %d", completed, finished);
}
```

Again any help would be appreciated, I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Comment: What is going on in `PsalmViewController setupView`? Is it possibly starting an async operation to "get" and/or format the verses?

Comment: No nothing asynchronous, it does load the text in, and puts it into the text view.

Comment: Hmmm... If you go forward / back / forward ... same result? Text doesn't appear until animation finishes? Is it *only* the text, or is it the entire view? Can you set the background color of the next view to see if it shows during the transition? Can you add a UILabel with static text to see if it shows during the transition?

Comment: Forwards and backwards is the same. Your a genius thinking to put another element on the page, as it draws but the text doesn't. Now to figure out why. Thanks